# How many points $P$ such that $\angle APB=\angle BPC=\angle CPA $ are there?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

Given that  $\triangle ABC$ is arbitrary. How many points $P$ such that $\angle APB=\angle BPC=\angle CPA $ are there?

Comment: Ever heard of the Fermat-Torricelli point? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**
If $P$ is inside $\Delta ABC$, the angles must sum to $360^\circ$, if $P$ is outside, the angles can never be all equal.
Can you now prove that $P$ must be unique? (It even has a special name)

Comment: Yes that puts $P$ inside the triangle, you can add a hint about its uniqueness as well.

Comment: @sciona Isn't the first hint sufficient already?

Comment: hmm .. perhaps you are right :) (+1)